How do I change the dot size in the SHAP beeswarm plot?
I'm using the shap library for python and pretending to use it with a couple of machine learning models. I'm just a beginner in all of this.
I have been trying to represent the beeswarm plot to understand how my models work. I am wondering how to customize the shap plots. I'm particularly interested in changing the dot size.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Shap library uses matplot lib. Therefore you can try to change all graph settings via matplot lib. The same thing changes the graphic title. However you did not add reproducible example therefore I cannot show you directly.
